# Simpifcation for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Pretty sure this is simple but can someone please point me in the right direction.

$n=1 : \frac{0.7^2}{1+0.7+0.7^2}$  =

$n=2 : \frac{0.7^2+0.7^5}{1+0.7+0.7^2+0.7^3+0.7^4+0.7^5} $

This will hold for other values of n as well. i.e for each n where the numerator has the sum of all $3n-1$ powers for each n>0 and the denominator has $ 1+ 0.7^1 + ...0.7^{(3n-1)}$ for each n>0.

Can someone tell me how this can be simplified to prove that no matter what the value of n the fraction always simplifies to $\frac{49}{219}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is 
$$
=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 0.7^{-1+ 3k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n (1+0.7+0.7^2) 0.7^{3(k-1)}} \\
= \frac{(1/0.7) \sum_{k=1}^n (0.7^3)^{k}}{(1+0.7+0.7^2) (1/0.7)^3 \sum_{k=1}^n (0.7^3)^{k}} \\
= \frac{0.7^2 }{(1+0.7+0.7^2) }\\
= \frac{49}{219}
$$
So you do not even need the finite geometric series sum formula.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^n=\frac{p^{n+1}}{p-1}$
And
$p^k +p^{k+3}+p^{k+6}+p^{k+9}+\cdots = p^k ( 1 + (p^3)+(p^3)^2+(p^3)^3+\cots)$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What you need for this problem is:

(1) Sum of a finite geometric series:
For any real number $a$ and for any $r\ne 1$ and for any nonnegative integer $n$,

$$a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^n=\frac{a-ar^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
And (2)
$$\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}=x^2+xy+y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum of a geometric series is given by

$$1+r+r^2+\cdots +r^k =\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}.$$

Apply this to the numerator and denominator of your fraction (where I let $r=0.7$):

$$\frac{r^2 + r^5 +\cdots +r^{3n-1}}{1+r+r^2+\cdots +r^{3n-1}} = \frac{  r^2(1+r^3+ r^6 +\cdots+ (r^3)^{n-1})}{\frac{1-r^{3n}}{1-r}}$$

$$ =  \frac{  r^2\left(\frac{1-(r^3)^n}{1-r^3}\right)}{\frac{1-r^{3n}}{1-r}}. $$

The $1-r^{3n}$'s cancel and you get

$$=\frac{r^2(1-r)}{1-r^3}.$$

Plug $0.7$ in for $r$ and you're done.